# Why java.util.List.clear() is an "optional operation"?

Tags: java, list

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear%28%29) :

> void clear()
>
> ```
> Removes all of the elements from this list (optional operation). The list will be empty after this call returns.
> ```

Why clear a List is an optional operation ?

This will not clear RAM to clear a List who contains thousands objetcs ?

Comment: @Joe this is not a duplicate as the other question only asks what is an optional operation whereas this question asks why a specific method is optional.

Comment: Check the comments and other answers. "if you have an ImmutableSet, then if makes sense for the operation to not exist" is already present in the existing question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible that a `List` is immutable.

What should be done when a `List` is immutable? You cannot clear an immutable `List` therefore the method `clear()` has to be an optional operation.

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with RAM clearance, its GC which would eventually Garbage collect those object.

Its more about cases where in clear cant do its job.

Example is when you try to get a list from array by call Arrays.asList(arrayObject), this list cant be modified. This operation results in java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: +1 Arrays.asList is not immutable, however the number of elements cannot change.